# Gitlab Runner - Dockerized flask app server fails connecting to database

Tags: docker, flask, pytest, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux

I have a flask web application and I run API automated testing with PyTest & MySQL database. When I run it locally, dockerized or not, the testing is successful.

Now the problem lies when running the dockerized procedure inside a gitlab runner (with Alpine Linux).

This is my gitlab pipeline:

```
before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add openssh
  - apk add --no-cache git

stages:
  - tests
 
tests:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - docker rm --force /myapp 2>/dev/null || true
    - docker image build --no-cache -t myapp .
    - docker run --name myapp -d -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service_account.json" -p 5050:5050 myapp
    - docker ps
    - docker exec -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service_account.json" myapp pytest
```

This is the output of the last 3 docker commands:

```
$ docker run --name myapp -d -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service_account.json" -p 5050:5050 myapp
096864c06de5fb2e8195cc1b87ab7635626759cb690dfc2d76eb640b3679c400
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
096864c06de5        myapp           "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0…"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp, :::5050->5050/tcp   myapp
790892bfc88e        b0757c55a1fd        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                                                        runner-uz9hfgtk-project-3669-concurrent-0-1be2fbd9916f7e7c-build
df641fdce08f        f8517f1ae7c9        "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 days ago          Up 6 days                                                           runner-uz9hfgtk-project-3740-concurrent-0-b0186612731c8779-docker-0-wait-for-service
$ docker exec -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service_account.json" myapp pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.18, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /docker-myapp
plugins: anyio-4.1.0, pylama-7.7.1
collected 50 items
Running tests...
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_ ERROR 
client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'app_factory'>>
    @pytest.fixture()
    def auth_client(client):
        basic_auth = get_basic_auth().popitem()
>       response = client.post(
            "/login",
            json={
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "password": "password",
            },
            headers={"Authorization": _basic_auth_str(basic_auth[0], basic_auth[1])},
        )
tests/conftest.py:33: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1039: in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/testing.py:222: in open
    return Client.open(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:993: in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:884: in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1119: in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2464: in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2450: in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1867: in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39: in reraise
    raise value
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2447: in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1952: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1821: in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39: in reraise
    raise value
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1950: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1936: in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_httpauth.py:172: in decorated
    return self.ensure_sync(f)(*args, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    @app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
    @auth.login_required
    def _login():
        connection = config_parcer()
        response, status = get_login.login(
            request, connection, app.config["SECRET_KEY"], bcrypt
        )
>       connection.close()
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
main.py:818: AttributeError
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
(1045, "Access denied for user 'app_user'@'XX.XXX.XX.XXX' (using password: YES)")
Connection refused. Attempts count: 1
(1045, "Access denied for user 'app_user'@'XX.XXX.XX.XXX' (using password: YES)")
Connection refused. Attempts count: 2
(1045, "Access denied for user 'app_user'@'XX.XXX.XX.XXX' (using password: YES)")
Connection refused. Attempts count: 3
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

As you can see the *docker run* command launches the server and it can connect to my database.
The errors start with the basic *login* post request from the flask app client when running pytesting.

How is it possible for the dockerized application - testing to be successful locally but not inside a gitlab runner? The docker container is supposed to be an isolated environment.

I thought that it could be a networking problem so I've tried using the *--network host* argument when running the container but to no avail.

Comment: Hmm. You've included a stack trace, but I don't see the actual error or exception class being raised. It's not clear to me what the error is or where the error is occurring. None of the paths in the stack trace seem to point to user code, which seems odd. Try adding logging and run pytest with verbose flags.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you just try to use something like `curl` to contact your endpoint. You should probably also check the application logs.

Comment: I've added more error traces. It looks to me like the Flask client tries to hit the server's endpoints but acts like it's not running, while it actually is. Locally works like a charm

Comment: Looks like a bug in your `config_parcer` function, which is returning `None` unexpectedly for some reason. Though, I don't really have any clues as to why it might work locally but not in GitLab CI. Though, I wonder if you just do something like `docker run ... myapp pytest` if that will work how you want. IIRC, I _think_ the flask test client spins up an instance of your server itself, so it's not necessary to run the server ahead of running your tests. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/testing/#sending-requests-with-the-test-client

Comment: Still the same error by just running the ```docker run ... myapp pytest``` command

Comment: Found the issue, thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

My flask app - PyTest setup had no problem after all. My mistake was that the Gitlab Runner built the docker image based on the corresponding repository that didn't contain the necessary SSL certificates to connect to my db. When I was running it locally, I set them up so there was no problem after all.